# Box hover transition/effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get this all transition hover effect in one only one box but I am unable to figure it out how to do, please help me to do... For this I am using html, css and also trying js with pagex and pagey event and mouseover and mouseleave event but it not working.

I have multiple cards. And in all that cards I want a transition. The transition is like that when we hover mouse from left, an overlay will start from same direction i.e. left and end to opposite direction i.e. right and cover all card, and if we remove cursor from any side like either top or bottom or left or right it end from there. And simultaneously, this have to work from all sides...

```js
const trans = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
for (i = 0; i < trans.length; i++) {
  let a = trans[i];
  a.onmousemove = function(e) {
    const x = e.screenX - a.offsetLeft;
    const y = e.screenY - a.offsetTop;
    a.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
    a.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #15151e;
}

.container {
  height: 220px;
  width: 455px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.b1 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 50%, #27eba7 50%);
  background-size: 400px 80px;
}

.b1:hover {
  background-position: 200px 0;
}

.b2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  bottom: 88px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 50%, #eec80b 50%);
  background-size: 400px 80px;
}

.b2:hover {
  background-position: -200px 0;
}

.b3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 34px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent 50%, tomato 50%);
  background-size: 200px 160px;
}

.b3:hover {
  background-position: 0px 80px;
}

.b4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  bottom: 121px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent 50%, #d964c0 50%);
  background-size: 200px 160px;
}

.b4:hover {
  background-position: 0px -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn b1">
    <a href="">left</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn b2">
    <a href="">right</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn b3">
    <a href="">up</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn b4">
    <a href="">down</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please desribe what effect you require - it's not working' doesn't help us much. Also you imply you are using JS but there is none in the code you give. Making your code into a runnable snippet could help us too. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you trying to get all of those transitions (slide from top, left, right, bottom) on one box based on the mouse position in the box?

Comment: Yes, you are right @disinfor. I have multiple cards. And in all that cards I want a transition. The transition is like that when we hover mouse from left, an overlay will start from same direction i.e. left and end to opposite direction i.e. right and cover all card, and if we remove cursor from any side like either top or bottom or left or right it end from there. And simultaneously, this have to work from all sides...

Comment: @RanishKumar can you post the javascript you've tried?

Comment: @disinfor , I used js in other file, if I will change all files it will take a lot of time so I only share my js code with you...

   ` const trans = document.querySelectorAll('.anchor');
    for (i = 0; i < trans.length; i++) {
        let a = trans[i];
        a.onmousemove = function(e) {
            const x = e.screenX - a.offsetLeft;
            const y = e.screenY - a.offsetTop;

            a.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
            a.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a good foundation for you to pick up and run with.

The Idea is to create two event listeners, one for a `mouseover` and another for `mouseout`. These can be used in conjunction to figure out what side of the element is being ***moused-over*** and what of the two *closest* *coordinates* ***percentages*** is the larger of the two, get this at the ***`mouseout`*** event and you have a good idea which slide effect and subsequent `background-position` to apply using javascript.

You can use the css hover effect for the *on* and *off* animations, just manipulate the ***classList*** of the event target to set and remove a directional class.

Define a couple of variables and utility/helper functions

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
const root = document.documentElement
// get the width and height of the element
// const rect = btn.getBoundingClientRect()

let delay = 800

root.style.setProperty('--delay', `${delay}ms`)

const direction = {
  up: 'up',
  right: 'right',
  down: 'down',
  left: 'left'
}

const removeStyle = ($this, prop) => {
    return $this.style.removeProperty(prop)
}

function removeClass($this, cls) {
    return Array.isArray(cls) ? cls.forEach(c => { $this.classList.remove(c) }) : $this.classList.remove(cls)
}

// helper function to return percentage 
function percentage(partialValue, totalValue) {
  return (100 * partialValue) / totalValue;
}
```

Run each button element through a loop and apply your event listeners and callback.

```js
btn.forEach(b => {
    b.addEventListener('mouseover', getMouseCoords)
    b.addEventListener('mouseout', getMouseCoords)
})
```

Pass the ***event*** into the function...

```js
// multiply the event y or x mouse coord with the elements 
// top or left and divide that by the overall height or width
function getMouseCoords(e) {
  // get percentages of x and y coords
  let y = percentage(e.clientY - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top, e.target.getBoundingClientRect().height)
  let x = percentage(e.clientX - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left, e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width)
  getEntryExit(e, x, y)
}
```

Now get the direction of the mouse event and check regions of the element to get closer relationship of x and y coords. Check ***upper/left***, ***upper/right***, ***lower/left*** and ***lower/right*** *regions* and compare the `x` and `y` of the mouse event.

Remember that ***50*** is a percentage of the height/width of the events region.

```js
function getEntryExit(e, x, y) {
  // check upper left area of clickable region
  if (x < 50 && y < 50) {
    // compare coords and setDirection depending on event.type
    if (x > y) {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('down', e, x, y) : setDirection('up', e, x, y)
    } else {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('right', e, x, y) : setDirection('left', e, x, y)
    }
    // check lower left area of clickable region
  } else if (x > 50 && y < 50) {
    // compare coords and setDirection depending on event.type
    if (e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2 - x > y) {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('down', e, x, y) : setDirection('up', e, x, y)
    } else {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('left', e, x, y) : setDirection('right', e, x, y)
    }
    // check upper right area of clickable region
  } else if (x < 50 && y > 50) {
    // compare coords and setDirection depending on event.type
    if (e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2 - y > x) {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('right', e, x, y) : setDirection('left', e, x, y)
    } else {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('up', e, x, y) : setDirection('down', e, x, y)
    }
    // check lower right area of clickable region
  } else if (x > 50 && y > 50) {
    // compare coords and setDirection depending on event.type
    if (y < x) {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('left', e, x, y) : setDirection('right', e, x, y)
    } else {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('up', e, x, y) : setDirection('down', e, x, y)
    }
  }
}
```

Then we have the `setDirection` function which will handle the animation by changing and manipulating the `background-position` and properties of the `event.target`. I use `setTimeout` to remove the `event.targets` *directional* *class* and `background-position` *properties* and reset the *positioning* of each one that was previously manipulated. The timeout delay is set using delay variable.

```js
function setDirection(dir, e, x, y) {
    let height = e.target.offsetHeight
    let width = e.target.offsetWidth
    
    if (e.target.classList.contains('btn') && direction[dir]) {
        // clear all directional classes that may be assigned to classList
        for (let d in direction) {
            btn.forEach(b => {
                b.classList.remove(direction[d])
            })
        }
        // set current direction class to element
        e.target.classList.add(direction[dir])
        
        // check each directional mouseout events coords and direction set in setDirection function
        // are we heading up and are Y coords less than half the size of elements height
        if(dir === 'up' && y < 10){
            e.target.style.setProperty('background-position', `0 -${height * 2}px`)
            setTimeout(() => {
                removeClass(e.target, direction[dir])
                //e.target.classList.remove(direction[dir])
                removeStyle(e.target, 'background-position')
            }, delay)    
        }else if(dir === 'down' && y > 90){
            e.target.style.setProperty('background-position', `0 ${height * 2}px`)
            setTimeout(() => {
                e.target.classList.remove(direction[dir])
                removeStyle(e.target, 'background-position')
            }, delay)
        }else if(dir === 'left' && x < 10){
            e.target.style.setProperty('background-position', `-${width * 2}px 0`)
            setTimeout(() => {
                e.target.classList.remove(direction[dir])
                removeStyle(e.target, 'background-position')
            }, delay)
        }else if(dir === 'right' && x > 90){
            e.target.style.setProperty('background-position', `${width * 2}px 0`)
            setTimeout(() => {
                e.target.classList.remove(direction[dir])
                removeStyle(e.target, 'background-position')
            }, delay)
        }
    }
}
```

In your CSS I added a couple of variables that can be manipulated later using Javascript. I also change the `:hover` properties using root variables as well. Lastly in CSS I changed the names of the ***directional classes*** to more reflect their directions, ie: `up`, `down`, `left` & `right`

```css
:root {
    --up-y-pos: -80px;
    --down-y-pos: 80px;
    --left-x-pos: -200px;
    --right-x-pos: 200px;
    --delay: 800ms;
}

.btn {
    border: 2px solid white;
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: var(--delay);
}
```

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
const root = document.documentElement
// get the width and height of the element
// const rect = btn.getBoundingClientRect()

// set a delay for all instances that will use it to synch 
// up animations I suggest a lower delay that will 
// reduce the potential for stuttering and doubling effects
let delay = 300

// set a root variable in CSS style for transition
root.style.setProperty('--delay', `${delay}ms`)

// define an object with key/value pairs for getting/setting
// event mouseover mouseout directions
const direction = {
  up: 'up',
  right: 'right',
  down: 'down',
  left: 'left'
}

// helper function to remove single inline styles
const removeStyle = ($this, prop) => {
  return $this.style.removeProperty(prop)
}

// helper function to remove classes from elements
function removeClass($this, cls) {
  return Array.isArray(cls) ? cls.forEach(c => {
    $this.classList.remove(c)
  }) : $this.classList.remove(cls)
}

// helper function to return percentage 
function percentage(partialValue, totalValue) {
  return (100 * partialValue) / totalValue;
}

// function to set class per direction of event
function setDirection(dir, e, x, y) {
  // get width and height of target element
  let height = e.target.offsetHeight
  let width = e.target.offsetWidth

  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn') && direction[dir]) {
    // iterate over the directions obj and clear all directional 
    // classes that may be assigned to classList of event target
    for (let d in direction) {
      btn.forEach(b => {
        b.classList.remove(direction[d])
      })
    }
    // set the current direction class to element
    e.target.classList.add(direction[dir])

    // check each directional mouseout events coords and direction set in setDirection function
    // are we heading up and are the Y coords less than 10?
    if (dir === 'up' && y < 10) {
      e.target.style.setProperty('background-position', `0 -${height * 2}px`)
      setTimeout(() => {
        removeClass(e.target, direction[dir])
        //e.target.classList.remove(direction[dir])
        removeStyle(e.target, 'background-position')
      }, delay)
    // are we heading down and are the Y coords greater than half the size of elements height?
    } else if (dir === 'down' && y > 90) {
      e.target.style.setProperty('background-position', `0 ${height * 2}px`)
      setTimeout(() => {
        e.target.classList.remove(direction[dir])
        removeStyle(e.target, 'background-position')
      }, delay)
    // are we heading left and are the X coords less than half the size of elements width?
    } else if (dir === 'left' && x < 10) {
      e.target.style.setProperty('background-position', `-${width * 2}px 0`)
      setTimeout(() => {
        e.target.classList.remove(direction[dir])
        removeStyle(e.target, 'background-position')
      }, delay)
    // are we heading right and are the X coords greater than half the size of elements width?
    } else if (dir === 'right' && x > 90) {
      e.target.style.setProperty('background-position', `${width * 2}px 0`)
      setTimeout(() => {
        e.target.classList.remove(direction[dir])
        removeStyle(e.target, 'background-position')
      }, delay)
    }
  }
}

function getEntryExit(e, x, y) {
  // check upper left area of clickable region
  if (x < 50 && y < 50) {
    // compare coords and setDirection depending on event.type
    // and x and y percentage relationship
    if (x > y) {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('down', e, x, y) : setDirection('up', e, x, y)
    } else {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('right', e, x, y) : setDirection('left', e, x, y)
    }
    // check lower left area of clickable region
  } else if (x > 50 && y < 50) {
    // compare coords and setDirection depending on event.type
    // and x and y percentage relationship
    if (e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2 - x > y) {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('down', e, x, y) : setDirection('up', e, x, y)
    } else {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('left', e, x, y) : setDirection('right', e, x, y)
    }
    // check upper right area of clickable region
  } else if (x < 50 && y > 50) {
    // compare coords and setDirection depending on event.type
    // and x and y percentage relationship
    if (e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2 - y > x) {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('right', e, x, y) : setDirection('left', e, x, y)
    } else {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('up', e, x, y) : setDirection('down', e, x, y)
    }
    // check lower right area of clickable region
  } else if (x > 50 && y > 50) {
    // compare coords and setDirection depending on event.type
    // and x and y percentage relationship
    if (y < x) {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('left', e, x, y) : setDirection('right', e, x, y)
    } else {
      e.type === 'mouseover' ? setDirection('up', e, x, y) : setDirection('down', e, x, y)
    }
  }
}

// fucntion to get coords on events
function getMouseCoords(e) {
  // get percentages of x and y coords
  let y = percentage(e.clientY - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top, e.target.getBoundingClientRect().height)
  let x = percentage(e.clientX - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left, e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width)
  getEntryExit(e, x, y)
}

// iterate over the buttons and apply event listeners for mouseover and mouseout
btn.forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('mouseover', getMouseCoords)
  b.addEventListener('mouseout', getMouseCoords)
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #444444;
}

 :root {
  --up-y-pos: -80px;
  --down-y-pos: 80px;
  --left-x-pos: -200px;
  --right-x-pos: 200px;
  --delay: 800ms;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 5rem;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: var(--delay);
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 50%, #27eba7 50%);
  background-size: 400px 80px;
}

.left:hover {
  background-position: var(--left-x-pos) 0;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 50%, #eec80b 50%);
  background-size: 400px 80px;
}

.right:hover {
  background-position: var(--right-x-pos) 0;
}

.up {
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent 50%, tomato 50%);
  background-size: 200px 160px;
}

.up:hover {
  background-position: 0 var(--up-y-pos);
}

.down {
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent 50%, #d964c0 50%);
  background-size: 200px 160px;
}

.down:hover {
  background-position: 0 var(--down-y-pos);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn"></div>
  <div class="btn"></div>
  <div class="btn"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey buddy, a big **THANKS** for helping me. But in this there is a bug. When we remove the cursor from same side / direction it shows opposite side’s hover style. Means when we hover from right side and remove cursor from opposite side i.e. left side it works properly, but when we hover from right side and remove the cursor from same side i.e. right side it shows opposite side’s hover style, which not have to be seen.